# What is $dudv$ in the metric tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, riemannian-geometry, tensors

In the definition of a $m$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,G)$, if $(U;u^i)$ is a local coordinate system of $M$, the tensor field $G$ on $U$ can be written as
$$
G = g_{ij}du^i\otimes du^j\;\tag{1}
$$

I have seen in many places people write the "Riemann metric"
$$
ds^2 = g_{ij}du^idu^j\;\tag{2}
$$
For example, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form#Calculating_lengths_and_areas) on the first fundamental form and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Arclength_and_the_line_element) on metric tensors.

In the context of tensors, it is clear what $du^i\otimes du^j$ and $du^i\wedge du^j$ mean. Sometimes the wedge product is even omitted. I have also seen people define
$$
dudv = \frac12(du\otimes dv+dv\otimes du)\;.\tag{3}
$$

What is the correct meaning of $dudv$ in (2)? Is it the tensor product, wedge product, or the symmetrization?

Comment: If $g_{ij}$ is symmetric, which is the case for a metric tensor, then it doesn't matter whether you use $du^i\,du^j$ as the tensor product or the symmetric product (but never the wedge product). You can try expanding out both expressions and checking that they are the same explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is exactly what you wrote in $(3)$. With this, we show that $g_{ij}\,{\rm d}u^i\otimes {\rm d}u^j = g_{ij}\,{\rm d}u^i\,{\rm d}u^j$ as follows: $$g_{ij}\,{\rm d}u^i\otimes\,{\rm d}u^j = \frac{1}{2}(g_{ij}\,{\rm d}u^i\otimes {\rm d}u^j + g_{ji}\,{\rm d}u^j\otimes {\rm d}u^i) = \frac{1}{2} g_{ij}({\rm d}u^i\otimes{\rm d}u^j+{\rm d}u^j\otimes {\rm d}u^i) = g_{ij}\,{\rm d}u^i\,{\rm d}u^j,$$where in the middle $=$ sign we factor out $g_{ji} = g_{ij}$.